# Mapping of half-life decay for all elements/isotopes

Tags: reference-request, isotope, databases, nuclear-chemistry

Is there an open resource that helps illustrate all paths of decay for all isotopes (e.g. $\ce{^{99}Mo}$ decaying to $\ce{^\mathrm{99m}Tc})?$ I know the result state/transition map would be massive, but am curious if anyone knows if something exists in open domain.

Bonus: In addition to the nature decay process, I'm also hoping to see if there is any documentation regarding known transitions we can trigger from different types of cyclotrons.

Comment: Why the downvote? I would appreciate inputs, if the question is unclear.

Comment: Check the links in the comments here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/119782/79678. A lot of information available! Have fun!

Comment: This one is cool: http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/.

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE, VenomFangs. Don't mind the anonymous downvotes. If your question is clear and on-topic, it will definitely be answered.

Comment: It turns out there are two kinds of scientists who use this kind of data, those who design nuclear bombs and reactors and their products on Earth, and those that study them in space, i.e. Astrophysicists. I think that [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) might turn out to be a better place for this question than here, even though it's a reasonable nuclear chemistry question. There are also some [nuclear engineers](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/12038/6264) at Engineering SE as well.

Comment: Mentioning cyclotrons, I guess the OP may be focused on processing nuclear waste by nuclear reactions, leading to a faster way to end with stable isotopes.

Comment: The National Nuclear Data Center noted by @EdV has a number of different resources for nuclear physics/chemistry. In addition to NuDat you might also be interested in the Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File (including searching By Decay), and the Evaluated Nuclear Data File which will give you data on neutron and gamma reactions.

Comment: My background is more software engineering, the example provided is just one common example I knew of when working on software tracking radioactive isotopes from birth to grave. As part of that process, I found out about different types of cyclotrons and that they can make many different isotopes. So I'm curious what we know they can make, what they decay to, etc. Really looking for a giant map showing states and ways we can transition them, need it be naturally or via processes involving cyclotrons.

Comment: Part of some of the medicine creation process sounded like they needed to go through a large series of steps to create something of use (the person running the cyclotron gave me an example of something that took 27 steps, but it wasn't feasible because of the short half lifes until they automated things more). So this questions is trying to get at the building blocks of transitions, which might be able to be used by people (or AI) to identify new processes we may be able to automate to create more useful medicines (or anything else for other fields). :)